# How to convert binary numbers received from a pipe

Tags: c, file-io, pipe

I have a pipe that contains a series of numbers.
I will read it and at each iteration I will write what has been read in a txt file.
How can I convert binary numbers to decimal numbers and record them, one per line, in my txt file?

PS
The pipe is created in another file and the numbers are written using this command:

```
write (fp, &mynum, sizeof (mynum));
```

Main file

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_BUF 1024


int main()
{

    int fd, fp ; 
    int bytesread;
    char * myfifo = "myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];
    int count = 0; 
    char *filename = "memorizza.txt"; 
    fp = open(filename,O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
  
    if ((fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY))==-1 ){   // opening pipe

        perror(myfifo);
        return 1; 
    }
 
    while(1)
    {
        if((bytesread = read( fd, buf, MAX_BUF - 1)) > 0) //read pipe
        {
            buf[bytesread] = '\0';
       
            count++; 
            write(fp , buf , MAX_BUF ); 
       
        }
        else {

            printf("Ho ricevuto %d numeri primi \n" , count); 
            break;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    close(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Write can be used for text files if you have characters. It will give unreadable results with binary data.

Comment: ok, so first i should convert what i read from the pipe from binary to char, and then go write it to the file?

Comment: fprintf does that for you.

Comment: How , can you show me an example?

Comment: How are the numbers written into the pipe? As text or as binary values? For binary you need to convers (`fprintf`), for text you need to thinkg about separators.

Comment: the numbers in the pipe are written like this: "write (fp, & mynum, sizeof (mynum));" where mynum is an integer, what should I do?

Comment: @LucaLucazzo Please [edit] your question and add all requested information or clarification there. Add a simple example program that writes a few hard-coded numbers to the pipe. When reading from the pipe you cannot assume to get the same number of bytes that was written with a single `write` call. You might get any number of bytes, more than one number or partial numbers, so you must check the return value of `read` to find out how many bytes it has read to the buffer. Instead of writing/reading binary data it might be better to `fprintf` the numbers in a text format, e.g. one per line.

Comment: I changed the description of the question

Comment: Are you sure you are using a pipe? It looks more that you are using a file. Have a look at the [documentation about pipes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html).

Comment: yes i am using a fifo pipe

Comment: @fpiette, FIFOs are also known as "named pipes", and when both ends are open, they are functionally equivalent to pipes established programmatically via the `pipe()` function.

Comment: As far as I know, the available method to make a FIFO(a named pipe), is the method `int mkfifo(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);`, from `#include <sys/stat.h>`.  Or the command line `mkfifo [-m mode] pathname`, but maybe that's not the point of the question. I also agree with @fpiette, that in the code there no a creation of a FIFO neither a pipe. If I'm wrong any correction is welcome

Comment: the pipe is created in another file

Comment: @LucaLucazzo Look at the [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) I already mentioned above. You use `open()` and this open a *file*. To use a pipe, you have to use `pipe()` and to open a FIFO, you have to call `mkfifo()`. I don't know what you mean when you say *"the pipe is created in another file"*.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it to you sincerely.
There is another file that creates the pipe and puts numbers in it ... the file I posted above has the task of reading the numbers in this pipe and writing them to a txt file.

Comment: Sooo when you say *a file* you mean the program resulting of compilation some source code in another file? How is the pipe created in that other source file ? To you create it using `open()` (That create a file on disk) or `pipe()` (That create a pipe) or `mkfifo()` (That create a FIFO)? For sure the program you show in your question do **not** open a pipe nor a FIFO but a **file** named *myfifo*. Giving such a name doesn't make it a pipe no a FIFO! Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Yes I have another program that needs to be compiled and run which creates a pipe with mkfifo ..
From the examples I have seen the pipes can also be read like this ... if you have other ways to do it I would be curious to see them.

Comment: OK. If you create using `mkfifo()` then you really have a FIFO and you have to open it using `open()`.

Answer (score 2):

To read a binary encoded int from a file descriptor (assuming host byte order), you have to pass a a pointer to `int` to `read`, and read exactly `sizeof(int)` bytes. A naive implementation would look like this:

```
int i;
ssize_t e = read(fd, &i, sizeof(i));
```

The problem with this implementation is that read is not guaranteed to give you all the bytes you asked for in one go. So we have to keep reading until we have all the bytes:

```
int i;
char *buffer = (char *)&i;
size_t left_to_read = sizeof(i);

while (left_to_read)
  {
     ssize_t e = read(fd, buffer, left_to_read);
     if (e < 0 && errno != EINTR)
       {
          perror("Failure reading from file descriptor");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
     else if (e == 0)
       {
          /* 
             Handle EOF
          */  
       }
     else if (e > 0)
       {
         left_to_read -= e;
         buffer += e;
       }
   }
```

EDIT:

Naturally after reading the `int` can be converted to ascii the normal way:

```
fprintf(outfile, "%d\n", i);
```

Comment: I just want to add that my solution is slower than it needs to. The implementation calls at least 1 `read` for each `int`. On a typical OS, every `read` does a context switch in the kernel, which is slow.  It would be better to read into a larger buffer than `sizeof(int)`, and extract the individual integers from that buffer. If the extra complexity is worth the gained speedup is something you have to decide.

Answer (score 0):

To a first approximation, if you write to the pipe with

> ```
> write (fp, & mynum, sizeof (mynum));
> ```

(quoted from comments), where `mynum` has type `int`, then the corresponding read would be

```
int fp = /* open read end of the pipe */;
int my_read_num;
read(fp, &my_read_num, sizeof(my_read_num));
```

When that works as intended, it gets you the wanted integer as an `int`, and you can then emit it without further manipulation via `fprintf()`, or otherwise do anything with it that you might ordinarily do with an `int`.

But there are complications, including:

1. Neither `write()` nor `read()` is guaranteed to transfer the full number of bytes requested.  Their return values tell you how many bytes they actually did transfer, and robust code needs to account for short writes and reads, generally by transferring any remaining bytes via additional `write` or `read` calls, as appropriate.
2. Calls to `write()` and `read()` are not guaranteed to pair up automatically.  That is, data written by multiple `write()`s might be read by a single `read()`, and *vice versa*.  That's not so much a problem for your particular case, however, (once you handle (1)) because you are transferring units of known size.  It normally bites people who try to transfer varying length data, such as lines of text, without establishing a means to also convey message lengths or boundaries.
3. In the fullest generality, you cannot necessarily rely on the two endpoints to use the same integer representation.  For instance, one end might use 32-bit big-endian for `int`, whereas the other end uses 16-bit little-endian for `int`.  There are ways to account for that, but you do not need to worry about it in your specific case, where both ends are running on the same machine and use the same C data type for the object they transfer.